# Why would a 5V LED strip require voltage higher than 5 volts?

Tags: voltage

I bought a strip of LEDs ([WS2812B LED Strip](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/BTF-LIGHTING-WS2812B-Length-Pixels-Waterproof/dp/B01CDTEJBG?pd_rd_w=uZbkS&pf_rd_p=926c607c-b514-42b2-b6cd-07056e360f14&pf_rd_r=182BMWQAN1ESDM2VY4CV&pd_rd_r=0d8ba62d-a352-40af-802f-c057c6875188&pd_rd_wg=4utAt&ref_=pd_bap_d_csi_pb_allspark_BIA_0_t&th=1)) and it is rated to operate at 5V. So I connect the LED strips to a bench supply with upper limit set to 5V. Everything works fine except after around 30 LEDs, the remaining LEDs won't turn on. Being a noob, I cranked up the upper voltage and until around 10 volts, all the LEDs were on.

Why would an LED strip rated for 5V need more voltage i.e. in the region of 10 V?

ps: Of course I turned up the voltage around 11, and some LEDs blew up too.

Comment: did you measure the voltage at the unlit LEDs?

Comment: Usually the LEDs get redder as the voltage drops along the strip, as the blue part of RGB requires a higher voltage. Did you see that?

Comment: Another remote possibility is that one of the LEDs is broken and doesn't pass the data signal along unless it gets an extra-high voltage.

Answer (score 3):

LED strips have a thin copper conductor for VCC which has some resistance. As such, there is a voltage drop as current increases. Measure the voltage at various points along your strip and you'll find that the voltage at the far end will be lower than at the supply end. For this reason, you should provide power at multiple points along LED strip runs (every 5 meters or so, but it depends on your strip characteristics and requirements).

Comment: Thanks, I will check the voltage drop across various points. By the way, my strip was  1.5 meters long (i.e. 90 LEDs combined).

Comment: It may be that your strip has a thinner copper track or plating than some I've used. Usually just running another power (and ground) using thicker (e.g. 20 AWG) wires to both ends of a strip will greatly help.